# How to use inversifyjs container as service locator

Tags: node.js, typescript, dependency-injection, service-locator, inversifyjs

I'm writing socket server for my IOT project (stm32f100 + WIFI esp)
I have implemented communication protocol such as GET query:
method=test&data[]=1&data[]=2...etc
I want to implement method resolver which will fetch service (controller)
 by method name from inversifyjs container with it's dependencies,
 but I can't find how to inject container into method resolver

Answer (score 0):

You can have multiple controllers:

```
container.bind<Controller>("Controller")
    .to(TestController)
    .whenTargetNamed("test");

container.bind<Controller>("Controller")
    .to(UserController)
    .whenTargetNamed("user");

container.bind<Controller>("Controller")
    .to(OrderController)
    .whenTargetNamed("order");

...
```

Then you can implement something like the following:

```
function getService(service: string) {
    container.getNamed<Controller>("Controller", service);
}
```

You can then resolve based on the method argument:

```
const orderController = getService("order");
const userController = getService("user");
```

Comment: I want to inject container into service which will fetch controllers from it.
And the question is: how i can do this